# Find the sphere with radius $\sqrt 6$ which touches an ellipsoid in a given point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vectors

> Find the center of a sphere $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2=6$ which touches ellipsoid $3x^2+2y^2+12z^2=42$ in $(2,3,1)$?

I thought of finding the normal vector to the tangent plane to the ellipsoid at point $(2,3,1)$. It is:
$$
n=\langle-\frac{x}{4\sqrt{42-3x^2-2y^2}},-\frac{y}{4\sqrt{42-3x^2-2y^2}},-1\rangle
$$
Then I thought getting normal unit vector: $n_u=\frac{n}{||n||}$.

Because the distance from center of the sphere to the point $(2,3,1)$ is its radius it is $\sqrt 6$. So I thought to multiply $n_u$ by $\sqrt 6$ and then plug in the point $(2,3,1)$. I tried doing this but the answer is incorrect.

What's wrong with my method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$z=\frac1{\sqrt{12}}\sqrt{42-3x^2-2y^2},$$ the correct normal vector would be $$
n=\left\langle-\frac{3x}{\sqrt{12}\sqrt{42-3x^2-2y^2}},-\frac{2y}{\sqrt{12}\sqrt{42-3x^2-2y^2}},-1\right\rangle.
$$ Your approach is correct, but keep in mind that there are in principle two such spheres, one touching from the outside (that's the one you need, probably) and one from the inside (though it doesn't fit entirely).
That would mean $$
n=\left\langle-\frac{3x}{12\,z},-\frac{2y}{12\,z},-1\right\rangle=\left\langle-\frac{6}{12},-\frac{6}{12},-1\right\rangle=\left\langle-\frac12,-\frac12,-1\right\rangle.$$ Its norm is $\sqrt{6}/2,$ so $$
n_u=\left\langle-\frac1{\sqrt{6}},-\frac1{\sqrt{6}},-\frac2{\sqrt{6}}\right\rangle.$$ Using that, we get the two solutions $$\langle2,3,1\rangle+\sqrt{6}n_u=\langle2,3,1\rangle+\langle-1,-1,-2\rangle=\langle1,2,-1\rangle$$ and $$\langle2,3,1\rangle-\sqrt{6}n_u=\langle2,3,1\rangle-\langle-1,-1,-2\rangle=\langle3,4,3\rangle.$$

Comment: The correct answer has $2$ points: $(3,4,3)$ and $(1,2,-1)$. According to my calculations $$||n||=\sqrt{\frac{504-27x^2-20y^2}{12(42-3x^2-2y^2)}}$$ therefore $$\frac{n}{||n||}=\bigg\langle\frac{-3x}{\sqrt{504-27x^2-20y^2}},\frac{-2y}{\sqrt{504-27x^2-20y^2}},-\sqrt{\frac{12(42-3x^2-y^2)}{504-27x^2-20y^2}}\bigg\rangle$$ Now if I plug in $(2,3,1)$ I get the following: $\big(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{6}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{6}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\big)$. Lastly we need to multiply the result by the radius distance $\sqrt 6$ so final result is $(-1,-1,1)$ which is not correct.

Comment: You're correct that there're 2 spheres and this is why the correct solution includes two points. but the $n_u$ vector doesn't give any of these points